# is there a command to convert svg to stl?

Tags: software-recommendation, files

Im doing some 3d modeling, and Ive been using inkscape to create 2D models, then importing them into openSCAD via a kinda superfluous method of uploading the svg files to tinkercad, downloading the file as an stl, then importing that into OpenSCAD. I searched things like svg2stl,and some keywords in synaptic, but I didn't find anything. is there a package that provides this functionality? CLI is fine, if not preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this question is already bit older, i'm not sure, if an answer is still needed.
In openscad 2021.01 svg files can be imported directly.
To create svg file from something like png, i first convert it into ppm (either imagemagick or gimp) and then run command `potrace --resolution 50 -e <my_image.ppm> --flat --turdsize 2 -O 0.3 --blacklevel 0.5 --alphamax 0.9 -b svg -o <my_image.svg>`
This now can imported by:
`import ("<path_to_file>/my_image.svg");`

Comment: I'll give it to you. I ended up openScad to do the conversion.